# MySQL LEFT JOIN on either of two columns

Tags: mysql, left-join

I want to join two tables on one of either two columns. I don't know which one will be a match. I want ALL records from feed_REIN and additional data when a matching row is found from listings table. I figured a LEFT JOIN would work.

When I just have the one condition (i.e. RETS.list_number = listings.CVMLS) it runs OK. As soon as I add the additional OR condition in the LEFT JOIN it takes forever to finish the query.

feed_RETS has about 125k records and listings has about 12k records.

What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT 

COUNT(*)

FROM feed_RETS AS RETS LEFT JOIN listings ON listings.statusID IN (1,2,3) AND (RETS.list_number = listings.CVMLS OR RETS.list_number = listings.REIN) 

WHERE RETS.public_status NOT LIKE '%Sold%'
```

Comment: No explain plan, no schema details, no stats, no example data and output: downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at explain plan to better understand the query with an OR clause. It's likely that the only possible join algorithm for this query is nested loop join, which is very inefficient for your tables. You can rewrite the query to something like:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*)
FROM(
(SELCT * FROM feed_RETS AS RETS LEFT JOIN listings ON statusID IN (1,2,3) AND RETS.list_number = listings.CVMLS WHERE public_status NOT LIKE '%Sold%')
UNION
(SELCT * FROM feed_RETS AS RETS LEFT JOIN listings ON statusID IN (1,2,3) AND RETS.list_number = listings.REIN WHERE public_status NOT LIKE '%Sold%'))T
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had considered that but was hoping I could accomplish what I needed with a LEFT JOIN and an OR clause. Obviously I'm not understanding the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*)
FROM feed_RETS AS RETS 
LEFT JOIN listings on
    RETS.list_number = listings.CVMLS 
    OR RETS.list_number = listings.REIN
WHERE public_status NOT LIKE '%Sold%' and statusID IN (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intend EITHER cvmls OR rein (exclusive or), and the application ensures that either can be true but not both, then logically the `LEFT JOIN` would be unnecessary, and the query would always yield the same row count. However, if both can be matched on the same row, then please consider whether you want COUNT(*) [all possible matches, including duplicates from the left side of the join] or COUNT(DISTINCT r.list_number) [only distinct listings]:

```
-- Query 1
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM feed_RETS AS RETS LEFT JOIN listings 
                                ON listings.statusID IN (1,2,3)
                               AND (    RETS.list_number = listings.CVMLS 
                                     OR RETS.list_number = listings.REIN
                                   ) 
 WHERE RETS.public_status NOT LIKE '%Sold%'
;

-- Query 2 - Is the count the same?
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM feed_RETS 
 WHERE public_status NOT LIKE '%Sold%'
;
```

If Query 2 returns a different count, then please be aware that there are rows from the listings table that are being counted multiple times. If you don't want that, then you need a count distinct—or perhaps one of the following refinements.

If the query is meant to limit the rows returned by all the criteria of this join, then you need an `INNER JOIN` (and for the sake of clarity may as well move the `ON` criteria into the `WHERE` clause):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM feed_RETS AS RETS INNER JOIN listings 
                                 ON (    RETS.list_number = listings.CVMLS 
                                      OR RETS.list_number = listings.REIN
                                    ) 
 WHERE listings.statusID IN (1,2,3)
   AND RETS.public_status NOT LIKE '%Sold%'
;
```

Your query may still be slow for two reasons (doing my best to diagnose based on general assumptions):

1. The `OR` in the `JOIN` criteria forces a full table scan, because the optimizer doesn't know which index to use or whether to use any at all.
2. The wildcard `%` at the start of the match string `'%Sold%` forces a full table scan, because the normal type of index is built by dividing the column content from left-to-right. Think of the index like a list of names in alphabetical order: if you're matching on the beginning of a name ("names beginning with 'Jo'") you can use your ordered list to find the matching names quickly; by contrast, if you're looking for something in middle of a name ("names with 'nat' in them") then your index is of no use to you.

This query may actually be faster:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
             WHEN l_cvmls.cvmls IS NOT NULL OR l_rein.REIN IS NOT NULL 
             THEN 1 
             ELSE 0
           END
          ) listing_count
  FROM (  feed_RETS AS r LEFT JOIN listings l_cvmls
                               ON l_cvmls.statusID IN (1,2,3)
                              AND r.list_number = l_cvmls.CVMLS
       ) LEFT JOIN listings l_rein ON l_rein.statusID IN (1,2,3)
                                  AND r.list_number = l_rein.REIN
 WHERE r.public_status NOT LIKE '%Sold%'
;
```

If you can avoid `'%Sold%'` and use `'Sold%'` instead, the query will likely be faster still.

Comment: `logically always the same row count` Are you sure?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40880/1

Comment: @Strawberry Good point. Let me rephrase: "If you intend EITHER cvmls OR rein (exclusive or), and the application ensures that either can be true but not both, then logically it will always be the same row count. However, if both can be matched on the same row, then please consider whether you want COUNT(*) [all possible matches, including duplicates from the left side of the join] or COUNT(DISTINCT r.list_number) [only distinct listings]." In my experience with these kinds of queries, the use case always calls for distinct rows (i.e., XOR). Darn logic! +1 for you :-)

Comment: @Zach-Victor Great info about the effect of the wildcard and forcing a full table scan. Thanks!